# How can I save a loaded document with content in GeckoFX control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xpcom, geckofx, html-editor

I am embedding the GeckoFX control in a Windows forms application in VB.NET.
I want to open a document from the Web in the control,
then I want to save the document with images, CSS, scripts, etc ...
The GeckoWebBrowser.SaveDocument(String) method saves only the HTML code of the document without the content.

I am trying this code instead, but it does not work:

```
    Dim gB As GeckoWebBrowser
    gB = sContainer.Panel1.Controls(0)
    Dim webBrowserPersist As nsIWebBrowserPersist
    webBrowserPersist = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIWebBrowserPersist)("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1")
    Dim fName, fDataPath As nsIURI
    fName = IOService.CreateNsIUri(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
    fDataPath = IOService.CreateNsIUri("C:\Test\Test")
    webBrowserPersist.SaveDocument(gB.DomDocument.NativeDomDocument, fName, fDataPath, gB.Document.ContentType, 0, 0)
    MsgBox(webBrowserPersist.GetResultAttribute)
```

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: I just do (in c#) _browser.SaveDocument(path, "text/html");

Comment: Hi, John. I can not check this in C#, but in VB.NET this method saves only the HTML part of the document, does not save images, does not change the src attributes accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that part of what you're trying to do. You should try filing a bug at https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/ (which ever version you're using). Understand, though, that geckofx is the kind of project where normally each user fixes the problems he runs into, then submits the fixes back to the project. If you don't code in c#, that might be a challenge.

Comment: Hi, John. That might not be a bug. I still hope I can make it work with webBrowserPersist. I have a code in JavaScript and it is working. Just need to adjust it to work in VB.NET.

Comment: have any luck saving the full page with resources?